# What is the keycode for control+z key in python?

Tags: python

I want to send some modem AT commands using python code, and am wondering what is the keycode for the key combination **control+z**

Answer (score 11):

Key code? If you send AT commands you are probably sending strings with ascii text and control codes, right? Ctrl-Z is usually 26 (decimal). So chr(26) should work, or if it's a part of a string, '\x1a' as 26 decimal is 1A hex.

That said, Ctrl-Z is not usually a part of the AT command set... so if this doesn't help you, maybe you could explain more what you are trying to do and why you would need to send Ctrl-Z.

Comment: `CTRL-Z` is used as end-of-message marker when sending SMS in text mode with the `AT+CMGS=...` command.

Answer (score 1):

I was using python3; none of these work for my problem and what I did was,

```
command_variable = chr(26)
ser.write(command_variable.encode('utf-8'))
```

this worked for me. you can concatenate it with any command.

Comment: But what is `ser` and how do I use it? I tried searching for a module with that name, but no such module was found. I tried running with `import ser` statement also, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
import serial
from curses import ascii   
ser = serial.Serial.. // your configuration
ser.write(ascii.ctrl('z'))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.